# Vaadin ui ready event

Tags: cloud, vaadin, vaadin-flow

in a cloud context I need to be able to find out when a spring boot vaadin service is ready for user connections.
I've tried a call to /actuator/health but the service is UP well before vaadin beeing ready ...
Has someone faced the same issue and found a solution ?

Just to make it clear, my issue is more at the load balanced level. I need to find a way to tell the load balancer (I'm using sticky session) that the new spawned vaadin service is ready to receive users ... this is where I've used the /actuator/health but the service is UP before vaadin is ready.

Comment: You should describe what you are actually trying to achieve, your question is too vague now. Read this chapter carefully first: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-application-lifecycle

Comment: I see, that you may be interested in Vaadin session or UI init event, but you could be as well interested in component level attach event or routing lifecycle events. There is simply too many options, so more details are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My issue is more at the load balanced level. I need to find a way to tell the load balancer (I'm using sticky session) that the new spawned vaadin service is ready to receive users ... this is where I've used the /actuator/health but the service is UP before vaadin is ready. So I think this is well before Vaadin session or UI init event no ?

Comment: Ok, This is something that is usually done in lower level of the stack than Vaadin. The most off the shelf cloud services have this mechanism built it between app server and load balancer configuration, so that app developers do not need to bother about this. Since you are are asking this I assume you are having custom on-premise setup, which requires some DIY. Vaadin does not have much info about how to do this in proper way. We usually rely on 3rd party integrations, like e.g. Hazelcast which is referred here https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/microservices/high-availability

Comment: Hi thanks your answer. No, I'm on a true cloud config and the load balancer rely on an http call to find out is a service is available. This method is quite common with load balancing processes. In general, services are candidate to receive connections as soon as visible from the auto discovery mechanism but here my service is visible before Vaddin beeing ready, so the need for an extra check. I've already spend a bit of time on the high availability with Vaadin but unfortunately this is not a viable solution because of the massive overhead it generates, so not for large scale deployment

Answer (score 4):

Our application (deployed on AWS with an Application Load Balancer) is based on Spring Boot and Vaadin 14. We've been using a ServletFilter to instruct the load balancer to direct traffic:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class HealthCheckFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String HEALTH_CHECK_PATH = "/healthcheck";
    private boolean vaadinIsInitialized = false;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith(HEALTH_CHECK_PATH) && vaadinIsInitialized) {                
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }

    @EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
    public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
        // invoked after Spring finishes loading the application context, which is after
        // Vaadin and the embedded application server has started
        vaadinIsInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

There are at least two interesting events that happen as part of the initialization of our application that could be used to indicate that the application is ready to service requests.

1. The [ServiceInitEvent](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.7.1/com/vaadin/flow/server/ServiceInitEvent.html) - This is published to any Spring bean that is implementing the VaadinServiceInitListener (you can register for this event if you are not using Spring, IIRC). According to the documentation is is published "when a VaadinService is being initialized." which means it happens before Vaadin is fully initialized. In a trivial application, I observed this happening a few milliseconds before the application was ready to receive requests.
2. (If you are using Vaadin with Spring) The [ContextRefreshedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) - This happens after both Vaadin and Spring are fully initialized. At the time of this event, the application is ready to service Vaadin requests - and thus it is a good candidate to use to signal to the load balancer.

Comment: Hi gruntled, thank for this, this is a great start. I'm going to dig this way.

Comment: Why do you use a Filter as opposed to a REST endpoint? Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: Hi, not tried with a REST end point, to be tested. For the moment, I haven't been able to get any vaadin ready status. VaadinServiceInitListener is all about UI so sessions. So the only solution I have for the moment is to catch the spring ready event and to delay the 200 healthcheck reponse code by an amount of time. I've set it to 2 minutes but I will need to refine this number with a production like system as vaadin beheaviour is not the same in dev and prod

Comment: @muzii I think the VaadinServiceInitListener is the way to go. It's about the **Service**, not about sessions. The Service can be initialized without any sessions AFAIK.

Comment: @Hawk - REST endpoint would work for most. A filter is more appropriate in my case since there is a subsequent filter that interrogates the ServletRequest host name to determine the the tenant. Since that filter won't recognize the health check request, using a health check filter prevents the tenant filter from ever seeing the health check.

Comment: @muzii You made me want to better understand the initialization events between Spring and Vaadin. I've updated my answer and its example based on what I've learned.

Comment: @Hawk ... sorrry, your are right about VaadinServiceInitListener, it is not only about sessions an d UI  ... just made a sortcut as there is SessionIni and UIInit listener but I dont think there is anything I can use in this case

Comment: @gruntled ... great answer. I will try that ! Many thanks for your help